# How to pass variable value to JScript in MVC view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application in which I want to pass the Variable to the JScript which is in that view itself.
How to do that?

I want to send the value of AccessMode to the Javascript.
I have declared that Variable but don't know how to use it in JScript.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model CRMEntities.Settings




@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomSettings3";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>CustomSettings3</h2>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>CustomSettings3</title>
</head>
<body>

       @{string AccessMode; }
     @{string Ratings; }


       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessMode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessMode)*@
            @Html.DropDownList("AccessMode")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessMode)
             //Assigning value.
            AccessMode = model.AccessMode
        </div>

         <div class="editor-field">

         @Html.DropDownList("RatingsCount")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RatingsCount)
         @{
             Ratings = Html.DropDownList("RatingsCount");
        }
    </div>


        <p>
            <input type="button" value="Save" class="SaveSettings"/>       

        </p>

</body>
</html>




  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function(){

    $('.SaveSettings').click(function ()
    {


           $.ajax
            ({

            type: 'post',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Settings/SaveBasicSettings")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
            { 'AccessMode': "@AccessMode" },
            success: function (data) 
            {


            }

            });


       });

  });

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `AccessMode` is just a string variable defined in your view, and your JS is embedded in the same view, you can simple write the value of the variable to your JS in the standard way:

```
{ 'AccessMode': "@AccessMode" },
```

Another way you can do this once you've moved your JS to a seperate file (if you choose to do so) would be to store the AccessModel value as a data atribute on the editor field.

That way your javascript can simply pick it up as it would any other attribute on a page.

**Update:**

The way you're assigning the value needs adjusting also:

```
@{
AccessMode = Model.AccessMode
}
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but it's not complete I don't think. Because `@AccessMode` will output a string, it will need to be surrounded by quotes or the javascript will interpret it as a variable name.

Comment: Thanks @JoelEtherton. I've updated my answer to include the quotes.

Comment: I have chenged, but its giving the error , CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'AccessMode' Whether my code is write ?

Comment: Nop, Its gives design time error, model does not exist in current context.

Comment: Yeah sorry..Upper case M instead of lower case.

Comment: Thanks a lot...It works... But I have lil bit issue.... I am using Dropdown in my view whn I get the its value, it sends old value not the new ... Please check image.

Comment: When I tried to pass ratings count value to JScript I get the value three. this value is assigned when page is loaded, If I select 5 and click on save, it send the old value 3 not 5.

Comment: Well yeah. In that case you just want to pick up the value from the dropdown right?

Comment: I tried this,  `@{
                 Ratings = Html.DropDownList("RatingsCount");
            }` but its giving error.

Comment: Well yeah. You want the value when Save Settings is clicked. So you just need to get the value via javascript rather thant trying to access it via Razor. Assuming the ID of your dropown is "AccessMode" then you'd do something like `$('#AccessMode').val()`

Answer (score 0):

if your value is set properly then can store it in Hidden Variable and read it in javascript

In View

```
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccessMode)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccessMode)*@
            @Html.DropDownList("AccessMode")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccessMode)
             //Assigning value.
            AccessMode = model.AccessMode

           @Html.Hidden("modelValue", AccessMode)  //set value in hidden variable 
        </div>
```

In javaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.SaveSettings').click(function () {
            var modelValue = $("#modelValue").val();
            $.ajax
            ({

                type: 'post',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Settings/SaveBasicSettings")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { 'AccessMode': modelValue },
                success: function (data) {


                }

            });


        });

    });

</script>
```

NOTE: check whether value is set properly in model.AccessMode in Hidden variable.